# Can't login to Apple ID on Xcode, `Unexpected nil property at path: 'Provider/attributes/developerTeamId'`

Tags: xcode

### Problem

In Xcode (`Version 13.2.1 (13C100)` and the latest beta, `Version 13.3 beta (13E5086k)`), trying to login to my Apple ID results in the error, `Unexpected nil property at path: 'Provider/attributes/developerTeamId'`. Has anyone got a solution to this?

### Observations

- this happens on multiple computers. So don't bother resetting your system. I am trying to use an older version of Xcode now. However, this might be an API issue (data sent back from Apple servers) which isn't structured well for Xcode.
- this affects accounts with **multiple teams**.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode preferences > accounts section]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Apple has fixed the issue

Apple has fixed the issue, you **don't need to update Xcode**, since it was an issue in their backend. <s>I've emailed the Apple developer support as this seems to not be an isolated issue. Trying the latest beta of Xcode, `Version 13.3 beta (13E5086k)` did not solve it.</s> This seems to have happened [1 year ago](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656161) as well.

### Temporary workaround

I've noticed that this only happens to me if my Apple developer account belongs to **multiple teams**. So I left all the teams except 1 in my alternative Apple ID.

#### Go to App Store Connect's ["Users and Access"](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users)

Go to App Store Connect > Users and Access > People > "YOUR NAME" > Scroll down > "Leave team".

[image]

#### Leave the team

Scroll all the way down, and click "Leave Team". You need to leave  **all the teams** except the one you're working on. Obviously, you'll need an invite later to work on those teams again.

#### Alternative

Alternatively, create a new Apple ID and invite that one to the team you need to develop for. Fortunately for us, Apple only broke Xcode, and not developer.apple.com. However, you'll need an Organization team, not an individual team.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. I had mac In Xcode (Version 13.0 (13A233)),(MacOS BigSur 11.6 (20G165))when i trying to upload my app to Test Flight .
I think if your apple developer account have multiple team id,May be Xcode unable to find correct app id.
I found one solution i install [transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) app and login through any apple id and select team id export your app and  add .ipa file .
Hola it works

Comment: how do you create an .ipa file?

Comment: In Xcode go to Product->Archive it starting build after some time you can export file in your system.
Make sure you select Any ios device from device selection.

Comment: I tried that (thanks for the suggestion!) but got: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. Did you have to do anything with the provisioning profile? I've always just let Xcode handle those details.

Comment: I got the same error when trying this even before this answer was posted. The `validate` step in the **Xcode organizer** would fail before Transporter is even used.

Comment: @MichaelRogers  you have to generate new development and distribution signing certificates and  add  these in keychain credential and also add new Provision Profile .
In this case you have to signin manually.

Comment: I've tried this answer, and didn't work out. The way Xcode packages your build doesn't give Swift Support, therefore you are going to be running into many errors. One solution to this was to package the SwiftSupport/iphoneos folders into the ipa, however, I still got many more errors after that.

Answer (score 0):

After writing to [feedbackasistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) the problem was fixed for me.

**Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)**

Comment: Hey @oguz, that link doesn't work for anyone except you, because Feedback Assistant submissions are private - I only see `Feedback Not Found`. If you want to share it, you could share a screenshot instead. Thanks for sharing that it is fixed. :)

Comment: sorry for that.  I changed the link to the main feedback assistant  url.  i guess everyone should submit their own feedback.