# Credentialed provider request failed with error: Unexpected nil property at path: 'Provider/attributes/developerTeamId

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, xcode13, apple-developer-account

In  *Xcode (Version 13.0 (13A233))*,**(MacOS BigSur 11.6 (20G165))** trying to upload my app to Test Flight getting this error.
Unexpected nil property at path: 'Provider/attributes/developerTeamId'.
Also try with new signing certificate and provision profile but still getting same error.
anyone getting same error having solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrAcu.png)

Comment: Update
 I found one solution i install transporter app and login through any apple id and select team id export your app and add .ipa file . Hola it works

Comment: See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70972034/11675817

Comment: Suddenly (random surprise from Apple) I also get this. EDIT: It went OK with transporter.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a solution in Xcode but at least there is a workaround.

1. Download [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/transporter/id1450874784) app from App Store into your Mac
2. Extract the ipa from Xcode Organizer
3. Choose ipa in Transport
4. Deliver

Comment: I attempted this but, Apple couldn't verify the build. Error I got, "Invalid Swift Support"

Comment: It is weird because I uploaded 10+ times with 2-3 different apps and it worked.